# How to iterate over dynamic objects

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonparser

I'm using newtonsoft json
To read a file with tests and i put it into a dynamic object.
this works nice for the static config part
However the tests part consists of tests, who's syntax is less static.
Some items can be different.

So my json file test.json looks alike:  (shortened)

```
{"config":{"user":"Nico",userID:"54"},
 "tests":[ {"ask":"test1","handshake":false},
           {"ask":"test2","handshake":false},
           {"ask":"test3","handshake":true,"verify":"true"}
           {"ask":"test4","handshake":false},
           {"send":"result4"} 
           {"ask":"test7","repeat":30,"delay":120,"brakefail":false} ] 
 }
```

I converted it to a dynamic object, and reading out the config part works nicely:

```
dynamic testfile = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText( "c:\\test.json"));
Console.WriteLine (testfile.config.user);
Console.Writeline (testfile.config.userID);  //this works
```

But now I wonder what is the syntax to iterate the tests ?
As they can differ slightly in options, how to parse them.
(the tests change high frequently).

Comment: You could create a `Test` class with your properties even though some may not be used. [Check](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MXQLiB) this example out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tests is an JArray. you can iterate the test with a simple foreach

```
foreach(JObject test in testfile.tests)
{
    if(test.ContainsKey("ask"))
        Console.WriteLine(test.GetValue("ask"));
}
```

but you need to verify that there is a variable like "ask"

Comment: in my case this seams the most handy way, with this i can ask for optional values and make constructs out of combinations of them.

Answer (score 0):

`JObject.Parse()` returns a JObject type that can be indexed with any valid string key like 'tests' in your case. Then you can use the returned value, which is of type JToken, to enumerate the items.

Here is an example:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse("{\"tests\":[{\"name\":\"Hana\"},{\"name\":\"Nita\"}]}");
foreach (var item in jObject["tests"])
            Console.WriteLine(item["name"]);
```

Comment: thanks i go for the other answer, its a bit more practical in my case, though it be good if there always was certainty of one iterating verb, which i'm not so sure of in the long run.